# Where is the mistake? Union of Cartesian products is the Cartesian product of the unions

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Let $U = \cup_{\alpha \in A} U_1^{\alpha} \times U_2^{\alpha} \times ... \times U_i^{\alpha} \times ... \times U_n^{\alpha}$ a union of Cartesian products. Let $\pi_i$ be the $i$-th canonical projection. I wrote a proof of $\pi_i(U) = \cup_{\alpha \in A}U_i^{\alpha}$ but I think that is not true.

> Let $y \in \pi_i(U)$, $\exists x \in U$ such that $y=\pi_i(x)$, moreover, $\exists \alpha \in A$ such that $x \in U_1^{\alpha} \times U_2^{\alpha} \times ... \times U_i^{\alpha} \times ... \times U_n^{\alpha}$, so $y \in U_i^{\alpha}$. Hence, $\pi_i(U) \subseteq \cup_{\alpha \in A}U_i^{\alpha}$. Now, let $y \in \cup_{\alpha \in A}U_i^{\alpha}$, $\exists \alpha \in A$ such that $y \in U_i^{\alpha}$, we can choose $x_1 \in U_1^{\alpha}$, $x_2 \in U_2^{\alpha}$, ..., $x_{i-1} \in U_{i-1}^{\alpha}$, $x_{i+1} \in U_{i+1}^{\alpha}$, ..., and $x_n \in U_n^{\alpha}$ such that $y = \pi_i((x_1, x_2, ..., x_{i-1}, y, x_{i+1}, ..., x_n))$ so $y \in \pi_i(U)$. Finally, $\pi_i(U) = \cup_{\alpha \in A}U_i^{\alpha}$.

Since, $U = \pi_1(U) \times ... \times \pi_n(U)$, it means that $U = (\cup_{\alpha \in A}U_1^{\alpha}) \times ... \times (\cup_{\alpha \in A}U_n^{\alpha})$, which I know is not true, so there is probably a mistake in the proof of $\pi_i(U) = \cup_{\alpha \in A}U_i^{\alpha}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First part is correct -- projection of union is union of projections. But $U$ is not the product of projections, unless it's something like a square.

Answer (score 1):

The error is the claim that
$$"\text{Since }U=\pi_1(U)\times\cdots\times \pi_n(U)\ldots".$$

Consider $A=\{1,2\}$, $n=2$, $U_1^1=\{a\}$, $U_{2}^1 = \{b\}$, $U_1^2=\{c\}$, and $U_2^2=\{d\}$. Then
$$U = (U_1^1\times U_2^1)\cup(U_1^2\times U_2^2) = \{(a,b)\}\cup\{(c,d)\} = \{(a,b),(c,d)\}.$$

Then $\pi_1(U) = \{a,c\}$, and $\pi_2(U) = \{b,d\}$. So
$$\pi_1(U)\times\pi_2(U) = \{ (a,b), (a,d), (c,b), (c,d)\}$$
which properly contains $U$.

**Note.** Technically, your argument assumes that all $\pi_i(U)$ are nonempty; but if any of them are empty, that means that $U_i^{\alpha}=\varnothing$ for all $\alpha$, so $U$ is empty and does equal the cartesian product of the unions.

Comment: Ok, so the first part is correct?

Comment: @dylan; yes, the first error is the assertion that $U$ equals the product of the projections. It is certainly *contained* in the union, but need not be equal to it, as the example shows.